# I could not compile this using AIP template, but it compiles in standard tex. How can I use the template?

Tags: equations, packages, templates

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{acknowledgement}{Acknowledgement}
\newtheorem{algorithm}{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}
\newtheorem{case}{Case}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}
\newtheorem{conclusion}{Conclusion}
\newtheorem{condition}{Condition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{criterion}{Criterion}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{solution}{Solution}
\newtheorem{summary}{Summary}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}


%------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{corollary}
\label{Corollary1}
Let $f:I\subseteq[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be twice differantiable mapping on
$I^{\circ}$, $a,b\in I$ with $a<b$. If $|f''|^q$ is convex, then
\begin{eqnarray}
\label{C1}
&&\bigg|\int_{a}^bf(x)dx-f(\frac{a+b}{2})\bigg| \\
&& \leq   \frac{(b-a)^2}{16(2p+1)^\frac{1}{p}}\bigg[\bigg(\frac{|f''(a)|^q+3|f''(b)|^q}{4}\bigg)^\frac{1}{q}
+\bigg(\frac{|3f''(a)|^q+|f''(b)|^q}{4}\bigg)^\frac{1}{q}\bigg] \nonumber \\
&& \leq \frac{(b-a)^2}{2^{(2+\frac{2}{q})}(2p+1)^\frac{1}{p}}\Big(|f''(a)|+|f''(b)|\Big). \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
\end{corollary}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{corollary}
\label{Corollary2}
Let $f:I\subseteq[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be twice differantiable mapping on
$I^{\circ}$, $a,b\in I$ with $a<b$. If $|f''|^q$ is convex, 
then
\begin{eqnarray}
\label{C2}
&&\bigg|\int_{a}^bf(x)dx-f(\frac{a+b}{2})\bigg| \\
&&\leq \frac{(b-a)^2}{48} \bigg[\bigg(\frac{3|f''(a)|^q+5|f''(b)|^q}{8}\bigg)^\frac{1}{q}
+\bigg(\frac{|5f''(a)|^q+|3f''(b)|^q}{8}\bigg)^\frac{1}{q}\bigg] \nonumber \\ \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
\end{corollary}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the posted code makes the error `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.` because `\begin{document}` is missing. Is that your question?

Comment: no it is not missing. there is another problem. But i could not find

Comment: Oh It _is_ missing, or at least, it is commented out, if you run the code as posted you get the error I state. I'll fix the above code this time!

Comment: by `aip` do you mean `\documentclass{revtex4-1}` and error `! LaTeX Error: No counter 'MaxMatrixCols' defined.` ?

Answer (score 1):

To use your document with `revtex4-1` rather than `amsart` I had to load `amsmath` and `amsthm` packages, and rename your `case` environment as that name is already defined, see the lines marked with `%%%%%%%`

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{acknowledgement}{Acknowledgement}
\newtheorem{algorithm}{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}
\newtheorem{mycase}{Case}%%%%%%%
```